# change DD-MM-YY to YYYY-MM-DD sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with date in DD-MM-YY and i would need it to convert to YYYY-MM-DD so it could be used for date manipulation? Does anyone have any idea how it could be done with sqlite query?

Comment: first of all, is it in an mobile application? If yes, how do you stack it into your sqlite db?

Comment: Hi, no it is on desktop, i solved it with string function, telling sqlitite what is year, what is month and what is date. then i updated new values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know the comments say you solved your issue, but for the benefit of others coming across this...

It would depend on the type of database where your original `DD-MM-YY` date was stored as to how to grab it.  It would not be SQLite, since SQLite stores it as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` (http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), as you said you needed.  But let's say you have a C# application that can reach in and grab your original date as `DateTime badDate`:

```
string goodDateString = badDate.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
string sql = "INSERT INTO MySQLiteTable (MyDateColumn) VALUES ('" + goodDateString + "')";
```

And then you use that `sql` with a `SQLiteCommand` and your connection string (path to your SQLite DB) to update SQLite.